# How can I make the function halt execution for n seconds in react js?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm simply trying to halt execution after every swap made in bubble sort so that I can see the changes, hence how can I make the function halt execution for a few seconds i.e. have a python equivalent of sleep() function in reactjs

```
bubbleSort(){
        const {array} = this.state;
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < array.length-i-1; j++){
                if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
                    let temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                    //halt for an interval on n seconds
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: you can use **useEffect** hooks

Comment: @MoshFeu I read that this is not the most effective way to use date

Comment: Maybe some way to use setTImeout() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom `sleep` function using **Promises** and `setTimeout` and use it inside your `async/await` `bubbleSort` like so :-

```js
let state = {array:[2,3,1,9,-23,4,5,6]}

async function bubbleSort(){
        const {array} = state;
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < array.length-i-1; j++){
                if(array[j] > array[j+1]){
                    let temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = temp;
                    await sleep(1000);
                    console.log('Halted');
                }
            }
               
        }   
      return state.array;
      }

function sleep(duration){
return new Promise((resolve)=>{
 setTimeout(resolve,duration)
})
}
    
bubbleSort();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks alot!

Comment: Exactly like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/863110) of the question I tagged :)